# Does anyone know how to convert this Teradata update statement to the same in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how to convert this Teradata update statement to correct SQL Server SQL?

```
 update a from DatabaseA.customer a,
      (select AcctNumber, sum( Amta - Amtb )
      from databaseA.TableA
      where TransDate/100=date/100
      and transtype in ('a','b', 'c')
      and acctnumber = 1234
      group by 1) thedata (aAcctNumber, OrderTotal)
      set  MonthlyInvTtl=OrderTotal
      where AcctNumber=aAcctNumber;
```

Comment: For starters I would stuff that derived table (named "thedata" - not clever) into a cte and then join the table to be updated to the cte. Just a guess but it seems a rather simple update involving old-style joins.

Comment: Thanks SMor.... not my SQL so can't credit for the clever names.  Appreciate the suggestion.  Everything is easy once you know how to do it.  We are converting to SQL so much is brand new.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might only need a transpose of the `SET` and `FROM` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

As [Smor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/140438/smor) indicated in the comment section, this Teradata query is using an old SQL join syntax, but is actually fairly straightforward to convert to SQL Server.

You have multiple options, below are a couple of simple ones:

Use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
;WITH thedata (aAcctNumber, OrderTotal) 
AS
(
    SELECT AcctNumber AS aAcctNumber
        , SUM(Amta - Amtb) AS OrderTotal
    FROM databaseA.TableA 
    WHERE TransDate/100 = date/100 
        AND transtype IN ('a','b', 'c') 
        AND acctnumber = 1234 
    GROUP BY 1
)

UPDATE a
SET a.MonthlyInvTtl = b.OrderTotal
FROM DatabaseA.customer a
INNER JOIN thedata b ON b.aAcctNumber = a.AcctNumber
```

Use a [subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15) in the INNER JOIN:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.MonthlyInvTtl = b.OrderTotal
FROM DatabaseA.customer a
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT AcctNumber AS aAcctNumber
        , SUM(Amta - Amtb) AS OrderTotal
    FROM databaseA.TableA 
    WHERE TransDate/100 = date/100 
        AND transtype IN ('a','b', 'c') 
        AND acctnumber = 1234 
    GROUP BY 1
) b ON b.aAcctNumber = a.AcctNumber
```

Comment: Thank you HandyD.... that is very helpful!